# Div populating but not showing in HTML5 tab

Tags: jquery, html

I have a div inside an html5 tab that shows the results of an RSS feed, which is populated from jQuery. The jQuery runs and the div is populated but for some reason the height attribute is always set to 0 which makes it unseen in the tab. If I place the div outside the tab, it works fine. Here is the code:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function () {
$('#rssFeed').rssfeed('http://news.google.com/news?hl=en&gl=us&q=alabama+football&um=1&ie=UTF-8&output=rss',{}, function(e) {
  $(e).find('div.rssBody').vTicker({ showItems: 4});
});    
});
</script>
```

And the HTML:

```
<div class="tabpage" id="tabpage_10">  
    <div id="rssFeed"></div>
</div>
```

Here's the link to the actual page:
http://www.inceptionsolutions.com/spread-option/division1-aa/sec/alabama-crimson-tide.html

Any help is appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: You are explicitly setting its height to 0px somewhere. That style is set directly on the element.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For whatever reason, the height was being set to 0 somewhere. It worked outside of the HTML5 tabs and I checked the HTML5 tab css and it wasn't being set there so not sure where it was being set. I added this to the RSS feed css to fix it:

```
.rssBody {
overflow: hidden;
position: relative;
height: 748px;
}

.rssBody li.rssRow{
margin:0px;
padding:0px;
height:187px;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Your "rssBody" class has a height of zero.